# Python airflow error AttributeError: 'xsensor' object has no attribute 'l'

Tags: python, attributes, airflow

I am new to Python and airflow. Trying to implement a sensor as below, and the error says "AttributeError: 'mySensor' object has no attribute 'l'"  I had a look at other attribute error questions, but I have no idea where the 'l' in my error comes from. Could someone help shed some light on this? Below is the whole class for mySensor. Many thanks.

```
class mySensor(SFTPSensor):
"""
Subclass of SFTPSensor to override the poke() method 
"""
template_fields = "previous_month"

@apply_defaults
def __init__(self,
             last_day_previous_month,
             *args,
             **kwargs):
    self.previous_month = previous_month
    super(mySensor, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def poke(self, context):
    remote_path = self.path+"file_to_check"+self.previous_month
    file_count = len(self.hook.list_directory(remote_path))
    if file_count == 0:
        return False
    else:
        logging.info("Found %d files", file_count)
        return True
```

and where I used the Sensor

```
sensor_task = mySensor(
                    previous_month=_previous_month_template,
                    task_id="check-remote-files",
                    dag=dag,
                    sftp_conn_id=my_conn_id,
                    path="/my/path/"
                    )
```

Comment: can you please format your complete error. It would be helpful to debug.

Comment: Can you change `template_fields = "previous_month"` to `template_fields = ["previous_month"]`? It is expected to be a list or tuple. Also I don't see `last_day_previous_month` argument being passed to the sensor but it is an expected argument in `__init__` function in your sensor

Answer (score 6):

I was getting a similar error with an Airflow operator:

> AttributeError: 'MyOperator' object has no attribute 't'

To resolve, check that the `template_fields` makes sense compared to your `__init__` arguments.

You have `template_fields = "previous_month"` but in your `__init__` there is no such parameter.

In my case, the `__init__` and `template_fields` did align. However, I had `template_fields = ("myfield")` instead of `template_fields = ("myfield",)`. The comma must be present.

Comment: wow this is a strange one, thanks for catching the fact that the comma is needed. It is not mentioned nor present in the docs: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.14/howto/custom-operator.html#templating

Comment: In Python ("xyz") becomes a string, whereas ("xyz",) is a tuple.
 
In BaseOperator the template_fields parameter expects a list / tuple of things to iterate through. Co-incidentally a string is also an iterable of strings which presumably breaks it. An issue has been logged for this - https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/12876 Just needs someone to contribute a fix :)